# How to access url parameters in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, http-request-parameters

I am working on a struts2 project. I have created url with  in my project and have passed parameters using  tags. My question is how do i read the parameter in the actions? also if do the same would i be able to see the parameters as query string. i ask because i am not able to and i saw it in one of the tutorials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, you will interact with parameters in your actions by using fields on your actions, exposed by setters. Assume the following URL maps to my example Struts2 action:

**URL**

http://localhost/myAction?firstName=SonOfTheEARTh

**Action Code**

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String firstName;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // do something here
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

**JSP**

Using Struts tags: `<s:property value="firstName"/>`

Using JSP EL/JSTL: `${action.firstName}`

Comment: does that mean we can send objects(other than String objects) as parameters. Also is it a good practice. also should the parameter be visible with url. because in mycase the url does not show the parameters

Comment: Yes, you can use other types of objects other than String. If it is a custom type, you'll need to create a Struts2 type converter for it.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED answer: It's based on naming conventions of your parameter. Take a look at this [link](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/struts-2-portlet-tutorial.html) and follow how they set "oldName" parameter.

Comment: i am working with struts2. i forgot to mention that. by url tag i meant <s:url>. to which you can pass parameters but i am not knowing how to retrieve them.