# passing parameters to urls in struts2?

Tags: java, struts2

I am working with a struts2 project and i need to pass parameters through url... this is the code that i have written

```
<s:url action="submit/CalculatePoints" includeParams="get" var="playerX" >
    <s:param name="winnerNo" value="player2"/>
```

it was refernced by following code

```
<a href="<s:property value="#playerX" />">
```

I expected that the markup for the link be

`submit/CalculatePoints?winnerNo=palyer2`

However iam not getting the querystring part. also attribute winnerNo in the action class is not getting populated as it should be according to [How to access url parameters in struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478147/how-to-access-url-parameters-in-struts2)

Please tell me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Player2 is being evaluated not as a string but an OGNL expression simply quote Player2 and the issue will be resolved.

IE:

```
<s:url action="submit/CalculatePoints" includeParams="get" var="playerX" >
    <s:param name="winnerNo" value="'player2'"/>
</s:url>
```

Comment: +1.  It was not obvious to me why it was only picking up values that were numbers and not any of the strings. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The [struts documentation for `<s:url>`](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/url.html) says this:

> The includeParams attribute may have
>   the value 'none', 'get' or 'all'

Since you set this attribute to 'true', the tag seems to be ignored.
Also, you must set the escapeAmp attribute to 'false'.  (I assume you have a closing `</s:url>` somewhere else in the code).

Comment: is the value of the property tag because the name of the url specified in the url tag's var attribute. and i thought this tag which you have written is for the pages that will be rendered using the url. i have modified the question to avoid confusion

Comment: My bad.  I actually did get confused ;) I'll edit my answer to solve your problem.

Comment: I've added some more info above.

Comment: still i am not able to get the output

Comment: Well, you should now.  I have triple-checked the documentation. Have you tried restarting your server or erasing the .class file in the server's directory for compiled JSPs?